# Adding member a ticket channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I need help with the tickets. When someone wants to call for help everything is fine, creates a channel and a message but does not add the author of the command to the ticket channel and does not even see him. I hope you will help me!

```
   @client.command()
   async def support(ctx, *, reason = None):
      guildid = ctx.guild.id
      guild = ctx.guild
      user = ctx.author
      amount2 = 1
      await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount2)
      channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket {user}')
      await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False)
      perms = channel.overwrites_for(user)
      await channel.set_permissions(user, view_channel=not perms.view_channel)
      await channel.set_permissions(user, read_message_history=not perms.read_message_history)
      await channel.set_permissions(user, send_messages=not perms.send_messages)
      await channel.send(f"{user.mention}")
      supem = discord.Embed(title=f"{user} Poprosił o pomoc.", description= "", color=0x00ff00)
      supem.add_field(name="Powód", value=f"``{reason}``")
      supem.set_footer(text=f"Wkrótce przyjdzie do ciebie administrator ")
       await channel.send(embed=supem)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've wasted a lot of code on permissions there, it's much easier.
You can use `discord.PermissionOverwrite` here and then ***use it like this:***

```py
@client.command()
async def support(ctx, *, reason = None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = ctx.author
    await ctx.message.delete() # Deletes the message of the author
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
    }
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket {user}', overwrites=overwrites)
    await channel.send(f"{user.mention}")
    supem = discord.Embed(title=f"{user} Poprosił o pomoc.", description= "", color=0x00ff00)
    supem.add_field(name="Powód", value=f"``{reason}``")
    supem.set_footer(text=f"Wkrótce przyjdzie do ciebie administrator ")
    await channel.send(embed=supem)
```

**What did we do/how does the new code work?**

- `guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)` excludes the default role.
- `user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)` the author, which you defined as user, has the permissions to read and write into the ticket.
- We created a new text channel with the condition `overwrites=overwrites`.
- I removed `guildid = ctx.guild.id` as you do not use it in your code.

***Example 2** on the following site explains it also very well: [Clik to re-direct](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107431/discord.PermissionOverwrite)*